# CSS Blend-Mode Multiply both background images replaced with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, background, background-image, blending

So I'm using CSS Background-blend-mode property, and how it works is: In the CSS you define two background images for the same div id, as seen:

```
#img2 {background-image: url(img1.jpg), url(img2.jpg);
background-blend-mode: multiply;}
```

If I want to change one background image of a div id through jQuery I can do it with the following code (Consider that icon is my variable where I keep the url of my image):

```
$('#img2').css({'background-image':'url('+icon+')'});
```

This works just fine! The problem is if I want to change both of my background images, for some reason it's not possible. Here's the code that I used in this case:

```
$('#img2').css({'background-image':'url('+icon+'),url('+iconSec+')'});
```

Does anyone know why doesn't it work or another way to change both background images of my div through jQuery?

Comment: I also tried adding a class and an id to the same div and change each background. It works, but the blend mode doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('#img2').css({'background':'url('+icon+'),url('+iconSec+')'});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I used, what happens in this case is that no image goes to the div background.

Comment: notice that i have used `background` instead of `background-image`

Comment: Make a fiddle demo if you can.